# Having trouble inserting data in MySql database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is just a testing page to make sure that I know how to insert data into the database.

This is my login page:

```
<?php 

$mysql_host = "[HOST REMOVED]";
$mysql_database = "a8700070_test";
$mysql_user = "a8700070_admin";
$mysql_password = "[PASSWORD REMOVED]";
?>
```

This is the code I have for the form.

```
<form action="db.php" method="post">

<input name="name" type="text">
<input name="age" type="text">
<input name="title" type="text">
<input name="person" type="text">
<input name="ok" type="text">
<input name="GO!" type="submit"> 



</form>
```

and this is the code I have that inserts it into the table.

```
<?php // 
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server= mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($mysql_database)  or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$namer = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$tit = $_POST["title"];
$k = $_POST["ok"];
$pers = $_POST["person"];

echo "$namer";

$sql="INSERT INTO test (title,person,age,date,ok)
VALUES($namer,$age,$tit,$k,$pers)"



?>
```

Comment: ...and what kind of trouble are you having, exactly?

Comment: Do you really want to share your mysql password with the whole world? A user with the same webhost as you would be able to access your database.

Comment: You must enclose the query values in single quotes, as in `'$namer'`. And you MUST MUST MUST escape them against SQL injection attacts. `$namer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Oops lol. It's just simple free webhost that I use for testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to actually call your query with [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query) like this:

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

You should also remember to escape your input to ensure a user wont abuse it with [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Your query should look like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (title,person,age,date,ok) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($namer)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($age)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($tit)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($k)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($pers)."')";
```

If you're getting an error, you could print the actual error with [mysql_error](http://php.net/mysql_error) like this:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You should also mention the possible mysql injections

Comment: I'm using this for the mysql_query and I'm still getting an error.

mysql_query($sql,$db_server);

Comment: Testing it again now and I'll let you know what happens.

Answer (score 1):

You need to seperate the variables in your SQL query with single quotes and should properly escape them...

```
$sql="INSERT INTO test (title,person,age,date,ok)
VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($namer)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($age)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($tit)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($k)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($pers)."')
```

And then actually run the query e.g.

```
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```